# Classification with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the original articles collection like this:

```json
{
  title: "how javascript closure works?",
  tag: "JS"
},
{
  title: "react hooks exploration",
  tag: "React"
},
{
  title: "Prototype link in Javascript",
  tag: "JS"
},
{
  title: "Component lifecircle in React",
  tag: "React"
}
```

The get url api: `/api/articles` with controller `getArticlesByTag` return this json array:

```json
{
  tag: "JS",
  articles: [
    {
      title: "how javascript closure works?",
      tag: "JS"
    },
    {
      title: "Prototype link in Javascript",
      tag: "JS"
    }, 
  ]
},
{
  tag: "React",
  articles: [
    {
      title: "react hooks exploration",
      tag: "React"
    },
    {
      title: "Component lifecircle in React",
      tag: "React"
    },
  ]
}
```

articles array should hold all articles with proper tag.

[image: api]

[image: controller]

How can I do this with mongoose and express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `Article.find()` call, you can use an `Article.aggregate()` call. You can pass in a pipeline to pass your docs through to reshape them. Something like this should get you started:

```
Article.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: "$tag"
        articles: { $addToSet: "$$ROOT" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: I changed the question. It must be clear now.

Comment: Yes that very much changes the solution. Please also add in what you've tried so far to query the mongo database.

Comment: Please check this question. I added some info.

Comment: I've updated this answer based on your new info.

Comment: I tested this solution with postman, but there has an error: "Use of undefined variable: root", my mongoose version is 6+, and mongodb version is 5+.

Comment: Ahh, you may need to capitalize that to "$$ROOT".

Comment: YES, I changed it. it works, but not perfect, here is another bug: "The field 'tag' must be an accumulator object". lol

Comment: Yep, not perfect but that should get you off in the right direction. I'm sure with some digging into aggregation pipelines you can figure out the next step.